# CASE statement Conditions postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a report for employees that start with the code 10....and apply a specific job code for them. They have a bad job code in the table.How and where do I check the condition in the case
statement ?

```
Example condition :
    Apply job_code 'AC' for the employees that start with the code 10.
```

**Table1 : customer_test**

employee_code

Job_code_id

company_code

join_year

**Table 2: Company_store**

Job_code_id

Job_code

Company_code

Join_year

```
SELECT 

ct.employee_code,ct.job_code_id old,ct.company_code ,cs.job_Code_id new ,cs.job_code new code,

CASE

    WHEN (ct.employee_code LIKE '10%') THEN CAST(cs.job_Code_id AS varchar) //I need to apply the condition here? apply the specific job code id based on the conditions.

ELSE CAST(cs.job_Code_id AS varchar)

END AS REPORT

FROM customer_test ct,company_store cs

WHERE ct.company_code=cs.company_code

and ct.job_code_id =cs.job_code_id

and ct.join_year=cs.join_year;

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
case
when employee_code like '10%' then
    (
    select  job_code
    from    customer_test
    where   employee_code ='AC'
    )
else cast(job_Code as varchar(50))
end
```

Comment: I can't apply the code 'AC'. I will have to apply the corresponding id for the code 'AC'.

Comment: You can do lookups with a subquery? Edited in answer

Comment: Thank you. Wil try and get back.